# How many "premium" hours between datetimes?

Tags: python, datetime

This is part of a bigger problem we're facing but the problem at the moment is splitting time between two datetimes into two rates based on *when* those hours are in the day. It's quite arbitrary but we treat 7am-7pm as normal hours and the opposite 12 hours as premium.

So for any given pair of datetimes, we need to grade these down so that we know how many normal hours, or how many premium hours there were in that period. A couple of examples:

If we took the next 24 hours, I'd expect an exact split of 12 hours.

```
> start = datetime.datetime.now()
> end = start + datetime.timedelta(1)
> split_hours(start, end)
(datetime.timedelta(0, 43200), datetime.timedelta(0, 43200))
```

If we took the next 12 hours, at 20:26, I'd expect 1h26 normal and 10h34m premium rate:

```
> start = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 6, 20, 26, 0)
> end = start + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
> split_hours(start, end) 
(datetime.timedelta(0, 5160), datetime.timedelta(0, 38040))
```

"How do I do that?" is my question. Sorry. I've been thinking through this most of the day but only ever got as far as the following napkin algorithm:

- Split range into distinct-date datetime ranges (how?!) and for each:

  - Count hours before 7am and after 7pm as premium
  - Count hours between 7am and 7pm
- Total them up.

But even there I don't know how to split things up.

There is also a natural extension —that I'll almost certainly have to implement at some point— that also grades weekend hours as premium too. If I could split time (as in my napkin algorithm) it would be easy to tack on but I still don't like how clumsy that "code" is). If your answer covers that too, you can have my firstborn. Well, no, you can have a bounty or something.

I'm doing this in Python without any real library limits (if eg Pandas Just Does™ this) but if you want to submit a raw C or Pseudo code answer, I'm sure I'll be able to read it.

Comment: For clarification: the smallest billable span of time in this case is the minute?

Comment: *Ideally* we'd be totting up raw timedelta. But if it comes to picking a lower resolution, minutes would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could:

1. generate a range of datetime between start and end
2. loop that range and calculate normal seconds (the length - normal = premium)

Here is the code:

```
import datetime

def split_hours(start, end):

    # Total seconds
    length = int((end-start).total_seconds())

    # Generator with datetime objects
    s = (start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(length))

    # Calculate normal and premium
    # normal when hour > 7 AM, smaller than 7 PM and weekday not sat,sun
    normal = sum(7 <= i.hour < 19 and i.weekday() not in [5,6] for i in s)
    premium = length - normal

    d = dict(normal=normal,
             premium=premium,
             total=dict(h=length/3600,m=length/60,s=length))

    return d
```

And now we can do some tests:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
end1 = start + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
end2 = start + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
end3 = start + datetime.timedelta(days=24)

print(split_hours(start,end1))
print(split_hours(start,end2))
print(split_hours(start,end3))
```

Returns:

```
# 12 hours
{'total': {'h': 12.0, 's': 43200, 'm': 720.0}, 'premium': 26131, 'normal': 17069}

# 1 days / 24 hours
{'total': {'h': 24.0, 's': 86400, 'm': 1440.0}, 'premium': 43200, 'normal': 43200}

# 7 days
{'total': {'h': 168.0, 's': 604800, 'm': 10080.0}, 'premium': 388800, 'normal': 216000}
```

Comment: Yup, this is neat. The only small change I've made is how you're evaluating normal. You can use the conditions as the value, rather than saying `True ... if ...`. I'll edit that in. Thanks.

Comment: I also don't think you need to range to length +1. That includes the last named second, which isn't usually included in a time range. So I edited that out.

Comment: @Oli You are right about that. I added +1 to correct for the range in python not counting last item when you start at 1. However running the code with your edits still works fine. Thank you for the edits, indeed made the code more "clear".

Answer (score 1):

That would be my approach:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def is_premium_time_period(start_time, end_time):

    start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
    end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")

    seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
    minutes = int(seconds / 60)

    premium_minutes = 0
    regular_minutes = 0

    for minute in range(minutes):

        premium_start = datetime.strptime("19:00 {}".format(start_time.date()), "%H:%M %Y-%m-%d")
        premium_end = premium_start + timedelta(hours=12)

        previous_start = premium_start - timedelta(hours=24)
        previous_end = previous_start + timedelta(hours=12)

        if premium_start <= start_time < premium_end or previous_start <= start_time < previous_end:
            premium_minutes += 1
        else:
            regular_minutes += 1
        start_time += timedelta(minutes=1)

    _premium_hours = premium_minutes / 60
    _regular_hours = regular_minutes / 60

    return _premium_hours, _regular_hours


datetime_01 = "06-11-2017 14:17"
datetime_02 = "06-11-2017 19:20"

datetime_03 = "05-11-2017 02:39"
datetime_04 = "11-11-2017 08:39"


print(is_premium_time_period(datetime_01, datetime_02))
print(is_premium_time_period(datetime_03, datetime_04))
```

EDIT: I'm sorry, I forgot to post what it returns:
It returns:

```
(0.3333333333333333, 4.716666666666667)
(76.35, 73.65)
```

Meaning (premium_hours, regular_hours)